# How to remove inconsistent spacing between math repeating math characters?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am creating a graph in Latex with auto-generated lines like

```
$|\circ\bullet\bullet\circ\bullet\bullet\rangle$
```

which generate the image

[image]

I would like the spacing of these symbols to be consistent and also small.

Ideally I would like all of the symbols to be spaced at the same distance as the last two symbols. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embrace `\circ`s and `\bullet`s, so that they don't take on special math spacings.

I believe both `\circ` and `\bullet` are declared as `\mathbin`, which will carry certain extra spacings when used in conjunction with adjacent tokens.  The bracing effectively isolates these tokens from "seeing" adjacent material (against which it would otherwise apply special math spacing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$|{\circ}{\bullet}{\bullet}{\circ}{\bullet}{\bullet}\rangle$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This makes the spacing consistent, but for some reason in python's matplotlib latex renderer I get large spacing, any idea why this would be?

Comment: @James I'm sorry, I cannot address that issue, other than to say the "natural" spacing would be font-dependent.

Comment: You were right, it was just because the font was set to some default which gave unnecessary spacing!

Answer (score 3):

You have the sequence of math atoms

> **Ord Bin<sub>1</sub> Bin<sub>2</sub> Bin<sub>3</sub> Bin<sub>4</sub> 
>   Bin<sub>5</sub> Bin<sub>6</sub> Close**

but **Bin** atoms are transformed into **Ord** atoms as soon as they don't fit the usual infix math notation. Thus **Bin<sub>2</sub>** becomes **Ord**, as well as **Bin<sub>4</sub>** and **Bin<sub>6</sub>**, so you end up with

> **Ord Bin Ord Bin Ord Bin Ord Close**

and finally TeX adds medium spaces around the remaining **Bin** atoms. This explains the picture *I* get from your input:

[image]

On the other hand, a different input such as

```
$\lvert\circ\bullet\bullet\circ\bullet\bullet\rangle$
```

would produce the sequence of atoms

> **Open Bin Bin Bin Bin Bin Bin Close**

that would be transformed into

> **Open Ord Bin Ord Bin Ord Ord Close**

producing a picture similar to yours

[image]

Neither input is correct.

Define your own symbols, because you're not using `\circ` and `\bullet` in their intended sense of binary operation symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\0}{\mathord{\mspace{1mu}\circ\mspace{1mu}}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathord{\mspace{1mu}\bullet\mspace{1mu}}}

\begin{document}

$\lvert \0 \1 \1 \0 \1 \1 \rangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\mathord` tokens are not actually required, but they show more clearly what we're doing.

See [LaTeX Theory - How Symbols are Modeled Under the Hood](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432708/4427) for more information about math atoms.